# I want to toggle an element whenever it is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I'm testing some things and i want `<div id="moreinfo">asddsa</div>` show up when I click a element, I disabled event with `.preventDefault()` but still not working here is the code also css display is `#cont1 #moreinfo { display:none; }`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#main').on('click', '.ppp', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('this').closest('#main').find('#moreinfo').toggle('fast');
            })
})
```

```
<div id="main">
             <div id="cont1">
                 <h1>Basic</h1>
                 <p>Buy <span>Basic</span> packet and get:</p> <p>300 Minutes Talk</p><p>500 SMS</p><p>5GB NET<a href="google.com" class="ppp"> More info</a><div id="moreinfo">asddsa</div></p>
                 <button>Buy Now !</button>

             </div>
```

Comment: try this:
  $("moreinfo").toggle();

Comment: Few things: **(1)** You don't need `event.preventDefault()` because clicking a `<div>` doesn't have a default behavior. **(2)** `$('this')` shouldn't have quotes. **(3)** If `this` refers to `#main`, then `$(this).closest("#main")` won't find anything. **(4)** If you're using IDs, you really don't need relative selectors because there should always be at most **one** element with a given ID. `$("#moreinfo").toggle('fast')` should be sufficient.

Comment: @TylerRoper #3 isn't quite correct, as `closest()` is self-inclusive: https://jsfiddle.net/nkL8rz17/. In the case of the OP it's completely redundant, but would still work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ahh I hadn't realized that, thank you. I can't edit that comment any longer but I'll leave it up for the surrounding information.

Comment: Actually my `(1)` is incorrect as well. I didn't realize that this was using event delegation - the trigger is the link `.ppp`, so really only `(2)` and `(4)` are correct/relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mistyped `$('this')` function , would you try this fix

```
$(this).closest('#main').find('#moreinfo').toggle('fast');
```

for better optimization try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ppp').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#moreinfo').toggle();
  })
})
```

and yes you need `event.preventDefault();` as `('#moreinfo')` is a Link and not a DIV so it has a default behavior .

Comment: @TylerRoper Thanks for pointing this out, I updated the Code also i did not want to confuse the user , anyway here is a [live version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeVNJr)